# How to force cp to writeback all the data before it finish?

Tags: linux, memory, cp

It seems that cp in linux won't write back all the dirty memory to the disk by default.  Is there any options to force cp writing back all the data before it finish?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the [sync command](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sync) after running `cp`:

> **sync** writes any data buffered in memory out to disk. This can include (but is not limited to) modified superblocks, modified inodes, and delayed reads and writes. This must be implemented by the kernel; The **sync** program does nothing but exercise the sync(2) system call.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I know sync can do the job.  However, I would like to know is there any options can apply to cp command and system?

Comment: Nothing about that in the [cp man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cp.1.html).

Comment: See this discussion : https://www.lucas-nussbaum.net/blog/?p=701